# Ubuntu doesn't display Firefox correctly

Tags: firefox, interface

Firefox's main window is always on top. Meaning Firefox's own menus and all of Ubuntu's UI is under it no matter the size of the browser. I tried all I could with Firefox suggestions of using safe mode, deleting themes, disabling hardware acceleration, nothing solves the problem.

What can I try on Ubuntu's side to try to resolve this?

Comment: Are you saying the very top of your monitor screen (Ubuntu's Global Menu bar) always have these words: **Firefox Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help** in it.  Do those words stay on the top even if you bring up an app such as LibreOffice and write a letter?

Comment: @L.D.James Only until it is not maximized then it changes back. But maximized Firefox is all you can use as it's all you can see.